# Can't paste resized image in Pillow

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a problem with pasting a resized image in Pillow module. I want to adjust a watermark to all images of any size with 1/3 width of the image width and maintain the ratio aspect 65:10, after pasting a resized image I get this error:

```
(480, 360)
(160, 25)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Przemek/PycharmProjects/cwiczenia/venv/project watermark.py", line 15, in <module>
    image.paste(watermarkResized, (0,0))
  File "C:\Users\Przemek\PycharmProjects\cwiczenia\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1504, in paste
    raise ValueError("cannot determine region size; use 4-item box")
ValueError: cannot determine region size; use 4-item box
```

Here is the code:

```
import os
from PIL import Image
directory = "PATH TO THE DIRECTORY"
watermark = Image.open("PATH TO THE WATERMARK")

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    image = Image.open("PATH TO THE DIRECTORY"+filename)
    imageWidth, imageHeight = (image.size)
    watermarkResized = watermark.resize(((int(round((imageWidth/3),0)), int(round(((imageWidth/3) /6.5),0))))).copy

    print(image.size)
    print(watermarkResized.size)


    image.paste(watermarkResized, (0,0))
    image.save("PATH TO THE DIRECTORY"+filename+".png")
```

Comment: use `//` instead of `/`and you get integer result - `imageWidth//3` - and you will no need `round()` and `int()`

Comment: `paste` needs four values `(0, 0, width, height)` or more detailed `(x1, y1, x2, y2)`

Comment: Thank you, I did that at first and then I experimented with round() function.

Answer (score 0):

`paste` needs four values `(x1, y1, x2, y2)`

In your code it could be

```
width, height = watermarkResized.size

image.paste(watermarkResized, (0, 0, width, height))
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by simply deleting the .copy function from the image object. I have another issue now. How can I paste an .png image with transparent backgroung into image?

Comment: Ok, I fixed this one too, thaks for help.